# Increment or decrement value in SQLite

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I need some help with SQLite. I've the following query that is supposed to decrement a value inside a database table if an user submit a form.
I'm testing the code, but the value will not be decremented or incremented. Maybe I made a syntax error? Another question related to the following query is about setting a limit to the increment, can I lock the increment inside the database table if an X number is reached? NB: I'm using php with `PDO`

Increment query PDO code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE rooms SET available_rooms = -1 WHERE available_rooms > 0');
```

Decrement query PDO code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE available_rooms SET available_rooms = +1 WHERE available_rooms != 2');
```

Comment: I think you probably want `SET available_rooms = available_rooms+1`

Comment: Or `SET available_rooms = available_rooms-1`